# Celery Flask Database Connection Error

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, celery, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to access my postgresql database from my celery worker.

Since I'm using factory pattern, I used https://github.com/mattupstate/overholt/blob/master/overholt/factory.py this link to create my celery worker.

I'm using `celery -A xyz.jobs worker` command to start my celery worker.

`jobs.py` file:

```
from xyz.models.user import User
from xyz.app import create_celery_app

celery = create_celery_app()

@celery.task()
def do_some_stuff():
    print(User.get_all())
```

When I call this task from one of my endpoints, I get the following error:

```
[2018-04-09 10:21:39,530: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task xyz.jobs.do_some_stuff[b3a71e41-2335-470f-89b8-f4844c6eba1c] raised unexpected: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/celeryTest/xyz_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 999, in __call__
    return self.registry[key]
KeyError: 4320768832

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/celeryTest/xyz_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/celeryTest/xyz_backend/xyz/app.py", line 30, in __call__
    return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/celeryTest/xyz_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/celeryTest/xyz_backend/xyz/jobs.py", line 10, in do_some_stuff
    print(User.get_all())
  File "/Users/user/Documents/celeryTest/xyz_backend/xyz/models/__init__.py", line 47, in get_all
    return db.session.query(cls).filter_by(**kwargs).all()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/celeryTest/xyz_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 153, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/celeryTest/xyz_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1001, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "/Users/user/Documents/celeryTest/xyz_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2950, in __call__
    return self.class_(**local_kw)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/celeryTest/xyz_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 143, in __init__
    bind = options.pop('bind', None) or db.engine
  File "/Users/user/Documents/celeryTest/xyz_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 877, in engine
    return self.get_engine()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/celeryTest/xyz_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 896, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/celeryTest/xyz_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 556, in get_engine
    self._sa.apply_driver_hacks(self._app, info, options)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/celeryTest/xyz_backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 830, in apply_driver_hacks
    if info.drivername.startswith('mysql'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'
```

I'm assuming that, the problem is with the database connection, but could not solve it. Is there anything that I'm missing?

`app.py` file:

```
def create_celery_app(app=None):
    app = app or create_app()
    celery = Celery(__name__, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    register_extensions(app)
    register_api(app)

    return app


def register_extensions(app):
    CORS(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)


def register_api(app):
    from xyz.api.user import auth_api_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_api_blueprint, url_prefix='/auth')
```

`extensions.py` file:

```
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Added full traceback.

Comment: How have you configured your flask app? Seems like there's some DB related configuration missing, namely the DB URI

Comment: @IljaEverilä Added my factory file as well

Comment: can you provide `User.get_all()` code and the configuration for your database

Comment: Next point of interest is `Config`. Have you defined "SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI" or such? The thing is that from looking at the traceback you can see that `info` is None. It is produced [from a call](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L557) to [`make_url()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.url.make_url) and returns None, if given None.

Comment: Just realized what the problem is. My config file had `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')` but I did not provide an environment variable for the worker. I was providing it for the flask app so there was no problem with it. My bad. Thanks for the help, appreciate it.

Comment: Consider changing that to `os.environ['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']` then, so you get a nice informative exception next time it is forgotten :)